# How to display month using ```DateTime``` in flutter

Tags: datetime, flutter

I have a calendar where i want to display the month above the calendar. Is there anyway to display only the current month?

(credits to https://github.com/adamstyrc/ for the image)

it should look like this :

[image: example calendar]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Get intl dependency from here [pubdev-intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).
2. Import the dependency by adding it to pubspec.yaml.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

List months = 
['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
var now = new DateTime.now();
current_mon = now.month;
print(months[current_mon-1]);
```

Answer (score 23):

Use the below package for DateFormat.

https://pub.dev/packages/intl

```
String returnMonth(DateTime date) {
  return new DateFormat.MMMM().format(date);
}
```

Just pass the date, the function will return Month. For ex. April,January

Answer (score 1):

It´s very easy with date_formatter;

Install date_format: ^2.0.2 in pubspec. [link](https://pub.dev/packages/date_format/install)

use this code:

```
String returnThisMonth(){
 var month = DateTime.now();
 final formatted = formatDate(month, [mm]);
 print(formatted);
 return formatted;
}
```

It will return you a string like 01, 02, 03, as january, february or march. Then you can use it freely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DateFormat` class:

```
String getMonth(int currentMonthIndex) {
 return DateFormat('MMM').format(DateTime(0, currentMonthIndex)).toString();
}

//currentMonthIndex 1 => "Jan", 2 => "Feb", ...
```

The [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) give a list of all skeletons (`M, MMM, m, MMMM`) and named constructors that can be used. ex. (`MONTH, NUM_MONTH, ABBR_MONTH`)

So alternatively:

```
String languageCode = Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode;
DateFormat dateformat1 = DateFormat.MMMM(languageCode);
DateFormat dateformat2 = DateFormat.MMM(languageCode);
String this_month = dateformat1.format(DateTime.now());  
//ex => August
String next_month = dateformat2.format(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 30)));  
//ex => Sep
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try table_calendar from the pub which is fully customizable and also you can able get current date current month selected date 
[table_calender](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar)

Comment: but this is a new plugin; i just want to know how to display the month using ```DateTime```.