# Trying to get month's name from loop index

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build a month selector (or dropdown). I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864088/how-to-display-month-using-datetime-in-flutter) but the answer was losing the localization capability. I want to be able to keep the localization support in my app instead of manually typing it but I don't know how to get the month based on the loop index.

```dart
class FormDropdownMonth extends StatelessWidget {
  const FormDropdownMonth({Key key, @required this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  final Function(int month) onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<int>(
      onChanged: onChanged,
      items: [
        for (var i = 1; i <= DateTime.monthsPerYear; i++)
          DropdownMenuItem(
            value: i,
            child: Text(
              DateFormat.MMMM(Get.locale).format(
                DateTime(year), // <-- How can I get month from i?
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Since it was only a single component and it's functionality is not more than selecting a month, using a plugin seems kinda "overpower" so I try to avoid it as possible. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61321189/14787573) from the linked question also works for your case, but an element is missing:

With the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl):

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


// Notice the `localeName` as parameter

String getMonthAsLocalizedString(DateTime date, String localName) { 
    return DateFormat.MMMM(localName).format(date);
}

final month = getMonthAsLocalizedString(DateTime(2022, 11, 29), 'en');

print(month); // 'November'
```

This will return you the month as a String while taking the localization into account.

Comment: but that would require the whole date to be passed. in my case, i only have the months, a number from 1 to 12.

Comment: @Yura You only have the months because you only care about the months: therefore, adding a year isn't a problem since you will get only the months at the end anyway.
That allows you to simplify your solution like this:

`for (int i = 1; i <= DateTime.monthsPerYear; i++) {`
`print(DateFormat.MMMM(localName).format(DateTime(2022, i)));`
`}`

Comment: well that make sense, I think your solution is better than mine.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution. I need to cast `i` as string and parse it using `DateFormat('M')` to get the month. Not a perfect solution but it works.

```dart
for (var i = 1; i <= DateTime.monthsPerYear; i++)
  DropdownMenuItem(
    value: i,
    child: Text(
      DateFormat.MMMM(Get.locale.toLanguageTag()).format(
        DateFormat('M').parse(i.toString()),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```