# Format date in flutter so that the month is in words

Tags: flutter, date, datetime, dart, format

I have an instance of DateTime, and i have formatted it to a string, but i would like for the month to be written in words rather than numbers, eg "1 June 2021" instead of "1 6 2021"

`DateTime _date = DateTime.now();`

`print ("${_date.toLocal().day} ${_date.toLocal.month} ${_date.toLocal().year}";)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`intl`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) package for this.

```dart
print(DateFormat('d MMMM y').format(DateTime.now()));
```

Answer (score 0):

2 easy steps to do it

1. Create a function

   String dateWithMonthName(DateTime date) {
   return intl.DateFormat('d MMMM y').format(DateTime.now(),);
   }
2. Pass the DateTime Like this

dateWithMonthName(date)

Answer (score -2):

I've followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864088/how-to-display-month-using-datetime-in-flutter#57864335) before and it worked.

TLDR;

1. Get intl dependency from here [pubdev-intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).
2. Import the dependency by adding it to pubspec.yaml.

   import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

   List months =
   ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
   var now = new DateTime.now();
   current_mon = now.month;
   print(months[current_mon-1]);